# Migrating to Spring Security 4 got Access deinied page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Im currently migrating to spring sec 4 but got trouble.
These are my setting down below.

My security.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Exclude all files and folders under resources for security -->
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <security:http  auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <security:headers disabled="true"/>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('RS001', 'RS002', 'RS003')"/>      
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/> 
    </security:http>

    <bean id="userDetailService" class="vm.security.UserDetailServiceImpl" />

    <!-- For hashing and salting the password -->
    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider"></security:authentication-provider>        
    </security:authentication-manager> 

    <bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailService" />
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    </bean>

    <!-- To load the message properties for overwrite default spring security error message -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:message"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Custom UserDetailSevice

```
        package vm.security;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

    import vm.data.dto.VmAccount;
    import vm.data.dto.VmSystemResource;
    import vm.exception.VmException;
    import vm.service.AuditLogService;
    import vm.service.UserAccountService;
    import vm.util.PropertiesConstants;

    public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        private static final Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(UserDetailServiceImpl.class);

        @Autowired
        private AuditLogService auditLogService;

        @Autowired
        private PropertiesConstants propertiesConstants;

        @Autowired
        private UserAccountService userAccountService;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userid) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
            try{
                VmAccount account = userAccountService.getVmAccountById(userid);
                if(account != null){
                    List<VmSystemResource> systemResourceList = userAccountService.getUserSystemResources(userid);
                    List<GrantedAuthority> roles= new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                    for(VmSystemResource resource : systemResourceList)
                        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(resource.getResourceId()));
                    UserDetails user = new User(account.getUserid(), account.getPwd(), (account.getStatus().equals(propertiesConstants.getCoreStatusActive()) ? true : false), true, true, true, roles);

                    logger.info(roles);
                    auditLogService.addAuditDetails(userid, new Date(), propertiesConstants.getAuthentication(), propertiesConstants.getLoginSucceed());
                    return user;
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userid + " not found."); 
            }catch (VmException ce){
                logger.error(ce.getErrorCode(),ce);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(ce.getErrorCode() + ":userid object is null");
            }

        }
    }
```

Login.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>      
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            /* For nav header not to overlap*/
            body {
                padding-top:150px;  
                background-color: #eee;                 
            }                                   
        </style>                            
    </head>
    <body>              
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form id="creForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">
                                <div id="errPanel" class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">
                                        <span style="color: red;">${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="userid">USERID:</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USERID" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>                      
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="name">PASSWORD:</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                         <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">                                          
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                                      
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is when i replace with old version spring security 3.2.7 it is working fine.
But spring security 4 always lead me to access denied page.
Hope somebody will help me.

Comment: Check your dependencies you added. Might be jars are not compatible with `spring security 3.2.7`.

Comment: Do you have a custom login page? If so make sure you changed the URL and input fields accordingly ... (The defaults changed).

Comment: @VigNesh I am using spring mvc 4.1.6 and spring security 4.0.2. Also i just put every dependency i need.

Comment: @M.Deinum . I have changed my login page according to migration guide but still not working. The problem is i couldn't get the roles for the access. :(

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean it doesn't get the roles? Are you even sure it gets the user? Please add your login page, what happens when you login? (enable DEBUG log for `org.springframework.security` to get more information about that).

Comment: @M.Deinum, i just added my login form, what i mean is if i put username with wrong password, it shows the error message. but if i put the correct password it redirects to the access denied page. It is checking the user but the <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('RS001', 'RS002', 'RS003')"/>  is not working

Comment: anyway i will enable the debug log and try it. thanks

Comment: What is the actual name of the role? `RS001` or `ROLE_RS001`? You are aware of the fact that Spring Security 4.0.2 isn't final yet but only milestone/snapshots?

Comment: Opps! sorry, i mean spring security 4.0.1, the actual role name is RS001.

Comment: when using `hasRole` (or related) the passed in value gets prefixed with `ROLE_` if it doesn't start with that, so the actual value used for checking is `ROLE_RS001` and that doesn't match `RS001`. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2758. You would either need to prefix your roles with `ROLE_` upon conversion or configure Spring Security to ignore the `ROLE_` prefix.

Comment: @M.Deinum i tried changing my roles to ROLE_* and you know what , it is working .. thanks a lot

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mind adding an answer (instead of just a comment) so it can be marked as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been several changes in Spring Security 4 changes to the defaults and also changes to make behavior more consistent. You are running into a change made for consistency ([SEC-2578](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2758)) meaning all `hasRole` (and it derivates) are now prefixing the incoming parameter with the role prefix which is by default `ROLE_` and this wasn't the case before Spring 3.2 (but was so in other places).

To fix you have 3 options

1. do as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-role-prefixing-disable) in the migration guide or
2. simply prefix your roles with `ROLE_` when converting them.
3. use [`hasAnyAuthority`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html#hasAnyAuthority(java.lang.String...)) instead of `hasAnyRole`